# How to use Issuu

Tags: issuu

I want to use Issuu to generate a document  by honsetly I didn’t understand how it works even using the issuu guide.

I don’t know how to use flash so I decided to use an Image as it mentioned in this link :
 http://issuu.com/services/customize/guide-howitworks.html  (The graphics file can be an Adobe Flash SWF file or basically any image on the web.)

I follow the instructions in this link:
http://issuu.com/services/customize/guide-configuration.html

First of all I have no website for the moment so I have used wampserver and joomla.

I have putted the files under wamp/www/Joomla

And then I follow the  document by typing the URL and it works:

```
http://issuu.com/jesper/docs/gan_issuu?mode=embed&documentId=080311154822-183d3d833
4a544518a0d5e324f2543d4&layout= http://localhost/Joomla/issuu / basicBlueCanvas-theme /layout.xml
```

then I don’t know what to do ,because the flowing link use flash:

```
http://issuu.com/services/customize/guide-modifyingthegraphics.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Issuu API: https://developer.issuu.com/

If you want to add a document this is the request you need to implement: https://developer.issuu.com/managing-your-publications/documents/upload/

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages along with "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)".